# \tabcolsep equivalent for rows?

Tags: tables, spacing

I know I can make tabular less cramped by changing `\arraystretch`, but what I really want is to make sure there are some fixed paddings above and below row contents, like what `\tabcolsep` does.

For example, I want to have more space for the 2nd row only:
[image]
But `\def\arraystretch{2}` gives me:
[image]
which IMO doesn't look elegant.

Comment: You should consider `cellspace` package

Comment: @JouleV Thanks, exactly what I want :)